# How to use Multiple ng-table inside one controller

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ngtable

I am not able to use wisely two ng-table inside one controller. I am dynamically creating ng-tables and compiling them. I am appending Multiple tables inside one controller.
For ex:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams<?php echo $data['bus_model']->business_id ?>" show-filter="true" class="tables">
    <tr ng-repeat="business in $data">
       <td>{{ business.name }} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a button which appends ng-table and then compiles them. But when I click on button to load one of the tables, so in console I see other tables also reloaded, I think because of **$data** variable. Can we use any dynamic variable instead of $data because when I add 5 tables, and then click on any of button to load one of the tables I see **"ngTable: reload data"** 5 times in my console.

Comment: please provide a plunkr or something similar

Comment: Can you show us some javascript... particularly whatever sets `$data`  ?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing what the server is returning with what the client is doing.

Comment: @lucuma: Create somwwhat similar [Plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQwNKkMFxCFnzlEzpBEg?p=preview) for your reference..

Comment: @VishalKhode if you can provide a succinct example it would help and I'll take a look.

Comment: @lucuma: Have you looked at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQwNKkMFxCFnzlEzpBEg?p=preview). My Issue is: Click on **Reload New Data**. I need new data to re-load on every click, but after 2-3 times, it doesn't load the new data.